# How can an index slow down a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing

I am having quite a difficult time at finding why adding an index on the foreign key of a table is slowing down the view of my colleague. This view is composed of several packed views with outer join and inner join. I tried to remove them one by one to figure out where the problem was, but I cannot say, it doesn't seem to come from a particular view but more from them all.

I knew indexes could slow down insert or that they were taking size on the hard drive, but I never read anywhere that they could be responsible for slowing down a view. The truth is when I do :

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO

select top 20 * from  MyView
```

It takes 20 seconds with the index and 9 without.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyField] ON [dbo].MyTable
(
    [MyField] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
  IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Did you look at the queryplan to see whats happening?

Comment: In theory, the index makes the optimizer consider more options when building the plan, which if it decided it needed a table scan anyway it could slow it down. However, I doubt that would ever have a measurable effect. Can you post the query that is affected?

Comment: Did you say that the view is a view that calls views (or did I misinterpret)? You need to stop that right away if so. These views must fully materialize all the lower views to work and are extremely slow when there are large amounts of data involved. It is a SQL antipattern to have view call other views.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know. I thought it was the same as having the the two queries joined in the same sql statement. I'll investigate this next week. Thanks for the tip! (BTW could you provide me a link where this could be explained, if not do not bother I ll look on the internet by myself, just in case you had some nice one..)

Comment: ok found this to explain : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/26/sql-server-adding-column-is-expensive-limitation-of-the-views-part-2/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible your OTHER indexes or stats are out of date.  If  they aren't current, it's possible the query analyzer is choosing a sub-optimal execution plan using your new index since it thinks that will be quicker.

Try running:

`UPDATE STATISTICS WITH (FULLSCAN)`

on your table.

Comment: That rocks dude! You saved my week!

Comment: Happy to help and glad it worked.  Issues like this are a pain to work through a lot of times.

Answer (score 3):

Are you selecting any other columns from MyTable? If so, you're probably doing a Bookmark Lookup (or RID Lookup), which means you're going to back to your table for the additional data.

You should place any columns that you additionally select in the `INCLUDE` clause of the index.

Run both queries with execution plans enabled and compare the 2, identifying which portions of the query take longer.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation, it didn't solve my problem but helped me understanding a bit more how indexes are working. Have a nice day!